# Update id based on parent cell value(s)

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive asked a question that i got a working solution for, BUT i need a little adjustment

here is the question i asked:

I have a database looking like this

Table name: person

```
id  name    country father_id     mother_id   HIV
52  bob     NULL    68            98          NULL
68  joe     Maui    72            14          CLEAR
53  mia     NULL    68            98          NULL 
51  robbie  NULL    68            13          NULL
98  Joyce   NULL    13            16          CLEAR
```

I need a query for my database where i update all person.id with HIV 'CLEARED' IF the mother_id and father_id both have HIV CLEAR please note i need to be able to choose the word i mark the child with, so this will not be the same value as mother_id and father_id.

I need the database to look like this:

> ```
>     id  name    country father_id     mother_id   HIV
>     52  bob     NULL    68            98          CLEAR
>     68  joe     Maui    72            14          CLEAR
>     53  mia     NULL    68            98          CLEAR 
>     51  robbie  NULL    68            13          NULL
>     98  Joyce   NULL    13            16          CLEAR
> ```

The solution i got look like this - and this works but

```
update person p join
       person father
       on father.id = p.father_id and father.HIV = 'Clear' join
       person mother
       on mother.id = p.mother_id and mother.HIV = 'Clear'
    set p.HIV = 'ParentsClear';
```

I need a little adjustment that makes me able to ask whether the

mother_id and father_id = Cleared OR Clear

i assume that is not as easy as this:

```
       update person p join
       person father
       on father.id = p.father_id and father.HIV = 'Clear' OR 'Cleared' join
       person mother
       on mother.id = p.mother_id and mother.HIV = 'Clear' OR 'Cleared'
       set p.HIV = 'ParentsClear';
```

?

Answer (score 1):

While it basically is "as easy", you need brackets **and** you should put your selectors in a `WHERE` clause instead of the joins. This makes the query faster in a typical deployment. Try something like

```
UPDATE person AS child
  INNER JOIN person AS father
    ON father.id = child.father_id
  INNER JOIN person AS mother
    ON mother.id = child.mother_id 
SET child.HIV = 'ParentsClear'
WHERE
  mother.HIV IN ('Clear','Cleared')
  AND father.HIV IN ('Clear', 'Cleared')
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
  mother.HIV IN ('Clear','Cleared')
  AND father.HIV IN ('Cl' at line 1

Comment: There was a spurious `;` at the end of the 6th line - fixed it.